# Sliding and fading effects

Tags: jquery, html, scriptaculous, effects

How do I come up with this, the sidebar and the top sliding bit:

[Apple iPad Page](http://www.apple.com/ipad/features/)

Scriptaculous or jQuery, etc.

I'd like this for one of my pages on my website to do the effects on load.

Thanks :)

Comment: get a coder... or http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page... or google it... :)

Answer (score 0):

On the Apple website it is done using Scriptaculous with the "slide" and "fade" effects. They also use the prorietary "-webkit-transition-delay" CSS command to delay the slide effect on the side navigation items. But as it is a webkit only CSS property, the effect is diffrent to browsers like Firefox.

A simple effect like in the top navigation you can get by using the function Effect.SlideUp().